# How should CategoryA override categoryB method

Tags: ios, objective-c, categories, swizzling

In `AFNetworking` 2.0, in `UIImageView+AFNetworking` there is a method:

```
+ (id <AFImageCache>)sharedImageCache
```

I want to override it and return here my custom object. I'd like also to override all the methods in `AFImageCache`, so basically I'd make a new protocol here. I've thought about method swizzling, however because lack of experience I'm not sure if it works ok with 2 categories. What if my category loads before `AFNetworking` category, will it still be working?

At all, is this approach a good one? I want to add disc caching to the memory one and I wonder which way is the cleanest one in terms of code quality.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use Categories to override a method. Per the documentation

```
"If the name of a method declared in a category is the same as a
 method in the original class, or a method in another category on 
 the same class (or even a superclass), the behavior is undefined 
 as to which method implementation is used at runtime. "
```

refer to the documentation at "Avoid Category Method Name Clashes" -->
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC.pdf

Subclass and override the method instead and use the subclass?

Analyzing your scenario, It make sense to do method swizzling.
Note: Make sure yourCache will behave the same way as sharedImageCache, else it will result in crash.

```
@implementation UIImageView (Swizzling)

      + (void)load {

                static dispatch_once_t token;
                dispatch_once(&token, ^{

                    Class myClass = [self class];

                    Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(myClass, @selector(sharedImageCache));
                    Method newMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(myClass, @selector(NewSharedImageCache:));
                    method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, newMethod);
                });
            }

            //This is just for sample. you can create your buffer in your own way
            static id <yourCache> yourBuffer;
            + (id <yourCache>)NewSharedImageCache
            {
                return yourBuffer;
            }

@end
```

Comment: How should i subclass category from AFNetworking? Or do you mean to rewrite AFNetworking?

Comment: If you have the source code modify the code to return your own object. Alternatively, you can write a new category with a different signature like `+ (id <YourDelegate>)YourMethod` and inside this if you need `sharedImageCache` then you can call `[self sharedImageCache]` to get shared cache, manipulate the cache/object within cache and return your own object.

Comment: I'm not willing to change source code for it as it may be done without it. With this category I don't think you are right - you don't know which one will be called, so it won't work.

Comment: Clearly the method name is different, so your method would be called. What you are trying to achieve with overriding the method?

Comment: In this case in each place in AFNetworking I'd still get an instance of sharedImageCache. The problem is that I want to swap sharedImageCache to myImageCache, so every method in that category in AFNetworking will be working on myImageCache not on sharedImageCache. The solution you gave me is working in a opposite way.

Comment: Updated answer, try method swizzling?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54677/discussion-between-naveen-prasad-r-and-vive).

Comment: Thank you for the source code, but I know how to swizzle methods. Please reread my question, I was asking how it works with 2 methods from categories - you never know which one loads faster. Unfortunately your answer still doesn't answer my question.